# Passing variable values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

May I know how to pass the values from $query if there is values in it. And if it empty, I would still have to pass the variables. I keep getting errors of undefined variable though the variables do exist in the sql database.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
include("header.php");

if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $uname        = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_name']));
    $email        = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_email']));
    $upass        = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
    $enroller_id_n = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['enroller_id_n']));        
    $enrolled_id_n=  $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['enrolled_id_n'])); 
    $direction = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['direction'])) ;
    $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = $MySQLi_CON->query("select * from personal where enroller_id='".$enroller_id_n."'");
    if($query){
        while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
            $enroller_id3 = $row['enroller_id'];
            $left_mem     = $row['left_mem'];
            $right_mem    = $row['right_mem'];
            $test         = "left_mem";
            $test2        = "right_mem";
            $direc        = $direction;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: pass the values from `$query` to *where*?

Comment: have you tried print_r on $query? What's the result?

Comment: pass the variables of $query for instance $left mem and $right mem. The problem here is Im getting undefined variable because my enroller id in personal is empty

Comment: learn about prepares Statements.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in _meow_ code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to try some debugging here. For example,

```
var_dump($enroller_id_n); // Check if the variable is not empty

$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("select * from personal where enroller_id='".$enroller_id_n."'") or die($MySQLi_CON->error);

$row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);  // Check your result array
```

Based on the comments, you need to remove that WHERE condition from the query and change it to simply:

```
$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("select * from personal");
```

Comment: but there is empty data inside. The page would not be displayed :(

Comment: You mean  $enroller_id_n is empty?

Comment: my enroller_id data is empty in the table personal. I just want to allow the query below to run if ($left_mem != $test && $right_mem != $test2 && $enroller_id3 != $enroller_id_n && $direc == $test) {   } even there is no data

Comment: Then you need to remove that where condition from the query and change it to simply:  $query = $MySQLi_CON->query("select * from personal");